# Can't replace attributes during a chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to override my default attributes set in the attributes file in my cookbook with ones set in the environments of my chef server.

This is my attributes file:

```
default['app']                  = 'tomcat_app' 
default['environment']          = 'env'
default['instance']             = 'tier'
default['application_name']     = "#{default['environment']}/#{default['app']}"
default['environment_instance'] = "#{default['environment']}/#{default['app']}/#{default['instance']}"
default['app_owner']            = 'app_user'
default['app_owner_group']      = 'app_group'
```

My environment it is configured as follows:

```
 {
    "app": {
        "tomcat_app": "NGS"
    },
    "environment": {
        "env": "/Test/Apps"
    },
    "instance": {
        "tier": "tst"
    },
    "app_owner": {
        "app_user": "ngsint"
    },
    "app_owner_group": {
        "app_group": "batchdev"
    },
    "override_attributes": {}
}
```

However during chef-client run these values are not replaced. I have set this in the default attributes of the environments.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes should be in `default_attributes` Hash/Object, it should look like:

```
  "default_attributes": {
    "app": {
        "tomcat_app": "NGS"
    },
    "environment": {
        "env": "/Test/Apps"
    },
    "instance": {
        "tier": "tst"
    },
    "app_owner": {
        "app_user": "ngsint"
    },
    "app_owner_group": {
        "app_group": "batchdev"
    }
  }
```

[As explained in the documentation.](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html#json)

Comment: I have done that and they are still not being replaced, am I doing anything wrong? I am still new to chef.

Comment: Are you using a role with default attributes? [It has precedence over environment](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence). As last resort you can try to use `override_attributes` in your environment.